# Response card in Amazon Lex does not show up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I tried to create a response card using the console but it doesn't show up and previously it use to give an option in slot(prompt) and now it is not showing up.

I'm building a chatbot from Amazon Lex, and I want a response card in Facebook Messenger, and I have been doing it without using a Lambda function, there was an option to display a card in the prompt (slot) before. However, yesterday when I tried to enable a response card, the prompt doesn't have the option for response card.

As per the Amazon Lex documentation the card has to work, but in my case, it is not even showing an option to enable a card from prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable the message inside Response
and then put any message 
after that you can enable Response cards.
may be this can solve your problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq9U2.png)